# PHP/MySQL nearest neighbor - long binary sequence

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, binary

Given an array of a series of long numbers (equal length) - 0101101111, 0111101111, 0101101101, etc.

Find closest match to 0101101001

OK, that's the short version. The long version is a form with 11 Yes(1) and No(0) questions (product finder). Since we know that the database may not contain an exact match to the n^r solutions = 2048, we need to find the closest match or, possibly, the closest two or three matches.

I'm guessing we need to compare each number in each position and rank the result, but I'm stuck on the solution - if I am even going about it in the right direction.

Thanks!!

***I did a quick check against popnoodle answer below***... using **$lookslike=11100110011;** running foreach, generated sql and ran in phpMyAdmin against a table of 6 "answers".

Answers were ranked as follows:

Answer -- rank

11100110011 -- 11
11100110010 -- 10
11100110000 -- 9
00000111010 -- 6
00000111111 -- 6
01101100110 -- 6

*edit for ranking explanation - 11 of 11 matches, 10 of 11 matches, 9 of 11 matches, 6 of 11 matches...

Very nice.

Added modified PHP manual example of multiple choice answers:

```
<?php
// Client Answers
$input = 'abcdbcdabcd';

// array of answers to check against
$answers  = array('abcdbddabcd', 'abcbbcdabcd', 'abcdbcccccd');

// no shortest distance found, yet
$shortest = -1;

// loop through words to find the closest
foreach ($answers as $answer) {

    // calculate the distance between the input word,
    // and the current word
    $lev = levenshtein($input, $answer);

    // check for an exact match
    if ($lev == 0) {

        // closest word is this one (exact match)
        $closest = $answer;
        $shortest = 0;

        // break out of the loop; we've found an exact match
        break;
    }

    // if this distance is less than the next found shortest
    // distance, OR if a next shortest word has not yet been found
    if ($lev <= $shortest || $shortest < 0) {
        // set the closest match, and shortest distance
        $closest  = $answer;
        $shortest = $lev;
    }
}

echo "Input answer: $input\n" . "<br />";
if ($shortest == 0) {
    echo "Exact match found: $closest\n" . "<br />";
} else {
    echo "Possible Alternative: $closest?\n" . "<br />";
    echo "Levenshtein Distance: $lev\n";
}

?>
```

Returns:

Input answer: abcdbcdabcd
Possible Alternative: abcbbcdabcd?
Levenshtein Distance: 3

Comment: You may want to look into the MySQL MATCH AGAINST method - not sure how/if it works with multiple fields, but I assume you can make some use of it - might be worth checking it out anyway

Comment: How will match against help here? From the info given it looks like just the one field which is a binary representation of a series of yes/no answers. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Field is binary representation of yes/no questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that much about SQL so this is probably not the slickest method but no-one else has contributed so far.

Compare each character in each position and rank the result.

rank = the amount of characters that are the same in the given comparison string "0101101001" as that in the string of answers in each row, so (N.B. You said 11 in your question but gave 10 digits as an example)

```
0101101001 against 0101101001 gives a rank of 10 
0101101001 against 1101101001 gives a rank of 9
0101101001 against 1111111001 gives a rank of 7
0101101001 against 0001100111 gives a rank of 6
```

As SQL

```
SELECT answers,
    ( #looking for 0101101001
    IF (substring(answers,1,1)=0, 1, 0) 
    + IF (substring(answers,2,1)=1, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,3,1)=0, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,4,1)=1, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,5,1)=1, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,6,1)=0, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,7,1)=1, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,8,1)=0, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,9,1)=0, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,10,1)=1, 1, 0)
    ) 
AS rank
FROM yesno 
ORDER BY 
    ( #looking for 0101101001
    IF (substring(answers,1,1)=0, 1, 0) 
    + IF (substring(answers,2,1)=1, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,3,1)=0, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,4,1)=1, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,5,1)=1, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,6,1)=0, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,7,1)=1, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,8,1)=0, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,9,1)=0, 1, 0)
    + IF (substring(answers,10,1)=1, 1, 0)
    ) 
DESC
```

As PHP

```
function getAnswers($lookslike)
{
    /* expects "binary" string
    returns the answers and rank (0 to string length) ordered by closest match first 
    */  

    foreach (str_split($lookslike) as $i=>$bit){
        $ifs[]='IF (substring(answers,' . ($i+1) . ',1)=' . $bit . ', 1, 0) ';
    }

    // use your db class
    return $db->select_many('
        SELECT answers,
            ( '. implode(' + ', $ifs) .' ) 
        AS rank
        FROM yesno 
        ORDER BY 
            ( '. implode(' + ', $ifs) .' ) 
        DESC
    ');
}
```

**Have not checked my code**

Comment: Thanks popnoodles. I think that's sorta the direction I am heading. Hoping to find a string diff comparison class or function that might help me rank string differences. My personal genome project (or albatrose). Thanks again.

Comment: a class, so in PHP? Fairly easy to write but it would mean selecting your entire database of results.

Comment: Hmmmm. Well, the client hasn't finished, but I'm guessing the results won't be more than 50 binary representations (product comparison). That is: 11 yes/no questions for each product - find closest match. So class might determine number of differences and rank accordingly. Make sense?

Comment: oh doesn't sound like a problem then, but to be fair that sql works. You want it written as a PHP function?

Comment: Yep! :) I am going to take a stab at the substring comparison also. Thanks!

Comment: php version added. can't see any reason to overcomplicate this. EDIT: wait, yes i can: fun.

Comment: Added some notes above. Code seems to work great! I don't understand ranking number, but results are ordered as expected. Thanks!

Comment: Edited to add ranking explanation - doh.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you are looking for is called the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).

It's fairly straightforward and not difficult to implement in whichever language you'd like.

[Here is how to implement the function in MySQL](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552)

Comment: Was not aware of Levenshtein function in php or MySQL. When comparing a small record set (<100) against single record input, I wonder if overhead would be any concern. Probably, not. Thanks for the great info!

Comment: Overhead is going to exist regardless of how you implement this, you are much better off having it process inside the database rather than pulling all the information out first to process.

Another benefit to this approach is it will work perfectly fine with multiple choice answers assuming it makes sense to do so (Strongly Agree to Strongly Disagree type). Lastly you should consider marking one of the solutions as acceptable, between all the answers and comments given you should have more than enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I do think this (Levenshtein) approach may be the best. For now, I finally have the client collaborating on a Google spreadsheet so we can see and refine product/qualification relationships. Something I **should** have done from the very beginning.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the information as a bitmask in an integer field, I think you can achieve the same result with a some bit operations:

```
SELECT value 
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY BIT_COUNT(~(value ^ test)) DESC
```

test being the value you want to test against.

An example would be with test being 11001 and value being 10101:

- 11001 XOR 10101 = 01101
- Binary invert (~) = 10010
- Count the number of 1 bits (`BIT_COUNT`) = 2
- And reverse the sort

Actually, I think you can shorten it to :

```
SELECT value 
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY BIT_COUNT(value ^ test)
```

This is essentially counting the bits that are different, so an ascending sort should return what you require.

Comment: Looks nicer than mine but I just get all bit counts = 64 with the first example and  0 with the second

Comment: @popnoodles: You're right, I had the wrong xor. The first version will return 64 if all bits are matching, because the binary inversion will pad the values with extra 1s.

Comment: Very elegant! But, alas this morning the client decides they want to add a few multiple choice questions to the test - ABCD! Arghhh.

Comment: Oy! Well, if you need to rethink your table design, I think that if you had a row for every answer, you could do some really funky stuff with joins alone. No need for bit magic!

Comment: Why is multiple choice a problem? You can still store them as a string CACDBAABDAD and compare

Comment: Yes, I edited above to demonstrate using php levenshtein() function taken from php manual.